# sql injection for educational purposes

Tags: sql, database, web-applications

I'm trying to exploit some web vulnerabilities in a sample website running inside a VM (it is not available on the web - only for educational purposes). I have a search criteria field and I write 'all' for display all products, or write or a specific product.

I tried inject code in field to search but doesn't work.

I tested:

```
' or 'UPDATE' 'products' 'SET' 'price'='0' 'where' 'price'='1000'--'
' or 'UPDATE products SET price=0 where price=1000'--';
all' or DROP TABLE products #
(...)
```

but typically return a message:

> SQL Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' ORDER BY PRICE' at line 1
>
> SQL Statement: SELECT pcode,price,description FROM products WHERE description like '%' or 'UPDATE products SET price=0 where price=1000'%' ORDER BY PRICE

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection for some examples of how such a vulnerability may be exploited. Note that SQL adapter needs to support *multi-statement* (eg. these are disabled by default in `mysqli`) requests to piggy-back a separate DML statement.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming. For security related questions use security.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 0):

even if unsure if i should give hints on sql injection here, 
in your statement is a ' to much in the last part.

1000'%' ORDER BY PRICE

Comment: This is a return after injection SQL:
I tried: ' or UPDATE products SET price = 0 where price==1000 but return this